# How can you use an ng-controller inside of a script tag/ ng-template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-controller, ng-template

I am working on a modal image pop-up. For the project I'm working on, the script/ ng-template seems to be the only way to get it to work. It works for one image when I hard code the ng-src like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="openModal">
   <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <div class="breath"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">
           <img height="429" width="750" ng-src="public/img/image1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />               
       </div>
   </div>
```

However, I want to be able to change the ng-src. I got some advice on here about this tried to do it with data binding, but I'm running into issues. For this, the below is my code and the error I get when I tried to add the ng-controller and data binding:

In the HTML:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="openModal">
  <div ng-controller="ModalCtrl">
    <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="cancel()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
       <div class="breath"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="container">
           <img height="429" width="750" ng-src="{{modalImg}}" class="img-responsive" alt="" />               
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

In the JS (where 'app' has already been initialized/ is used for other controllers in other parts of the code):

```
app.controller('ModalCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.modalImg = "public/img/image1.jpg";
});
```

Note that I just hard coded the path in the controller there to test but will hopefully be using the controller to change the image path if I can get this to work.

After adding these though, I get the error:

Error: [$compile:tpload] and it links to:
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=openModal&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found

I am fairly new to angular, and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why you deleted the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662700/how-can-i-use-an-ng-controller-in-a-script-tag) and then re-posted it, but I still think the problem is not with `ng-controller`.  wherever you are trying to load this `openModal` template, it cannot find the template, which is exactly what this error says.  There is nothing suggesting that an `ng-controller` anywhere would be at fault.

Comment: the error linked also says as much: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tpload?p0=openModal&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found "This error occurs when $compile attempts to fetch a template from some URL, and the request fails.

To resolve this error, ensure that the URL of the template is spelled correctly and resolves to correct absolute URL. The Chrome Developer Tools might also be helpful in determining why the request failed.

If you are using $templateCache to pre-load templates, ensure that the cache was populated with the template."

Comment: it's also possible that the script itself isn't loading into the template cache due to syntax errors;  in particular, `ng-src="{{modalImg}"` is missing a `}`.

Comment: @Claies I didn't think I phrased it well. The reason I think it's the controller and not the template is because the template loads and works fine before I added the controller (added that to the top part of this). I am able to call openModal and see the modal when the ng-src is hard coded. When I added the controller to attempt data binding, I now get the error.

Comment: @Claies The missing } was just in the text above from me changing some of the names for confidentiality of the project. I edited to fix.

Comment: well I think you will have to create a [mcve] of the issue;  there isn't anything that prevents you from using `ng-controller` in this situation, and there isn't any reason that adding `ng-controller` would cause the template to fail to load.....

Comment: @Claies ok I'm sorry. I am new to posting. I realize that it shouldn't and I don't know why it is. That is why I'm posting here to try and get some help.

Comment: do you have ng-app="yourApp" on the page where you are trying to add the controller?